# Odoo form view create new form instead showing existing

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

Every time when I click on My module menu it jump to new form instead of showing existing, I assigned access rule to my module and disable create and edit but still didn't work, what I want is when I click on my module menu it should open an existing form or I can use domain like user_id field = user.name.

This is my code.

```
     <record id="action_ru_students" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Students</field>
        <field name="res_model">ru.students</field>
        <field name="view_id" ref="students_form_view"/>
        <field name="view_mode">form,kanban,tree</field>
    </record>
```

I tried to use domain on action e.g. = `[("user_id","=",user.name)]`
user_id is a field linked to res.user but get error user.name not found.
also used `create="false" and edit="false"` on form still no luck.

Any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Use sequence Tree,kanban,form in view_mode

```
<record id="action_ru_students" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">Students</field>
    <field name="res_model">ru.students</field>
    <field name="view_id" ref="students_form_view"/>
    <field name="view_mode">tree,kanban,form</field>
</record>
```

It might be helpful to you!

Comment: Yes it works but i want to view form first i am using the form instead of dashboard so when the module is clicked the form showed come up not tree.

Comment: @Omeed I don't really understand when you said "Every time when I click on My module menu it jump to new form instead of showing existing" do you want to show a record in the form insteading of creating new record

Comment: @noble_man yes it should open the existing form which is related to the current user. i am using domain on the menu e.g. domain="[('user_id','=',uid)]" domain works fine for tree view but if i change the view_mode sequence to form it create new one.